# static variables inside a C++ method

Tags: c++, methods

As a C programmer, I'd like to ask a question related to C++.

Suppose doSomething(), which has a static local variable, is a public method of a class in C++. And suppose we have created two instances of this class.

Now, is there only one copy of this static variable in memory, shared between the two instances? I guess this should be the case.

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there only one copy of this static variable in memory, shared
>   between the two instances?

Yes

Answer (score 0):

The lifetime of the static variable is from the time the program flow encounters the declaration to when the program terminates. It is shared by any instance of the class.